# Handle muliple push notifications click in Android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM notification in my android application. When the application is on background, the notification click navigates to the MainActivity. This only happens when there is only one notification, When there are multiple notifications, only the last notification is able to start the application.
Notification click is not happening once the app comes to foreground. If I close the app and click the next notification from notification bar, then the app opens again.

I think there a problem with the notification action in the notification payload.

```
   <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup">

    <!-- tools:replace="android:theme" -->
    <!-- Launch Flow -->
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="myAction" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
    <service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END firebase_service] -->


    <!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
    <service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END firebase_iid_service] -->


</application>
```

This is my notification json.

```
{

"notification":{
    "title":"Jogn Doe",
    "body":"Jogn commented on your post",
    "sound":"mySound",
    "tag":"88211407420864",
    "click_action":"myAction"
},
"data":{
    "notificationCount":2,
    "creatorName":"John Doe",
    "creatorImage":"https://image.com/sample.png",
    "notificationId":"88335540289536",
    "universityId":"8821098664448"
},
    "to":"fYu_ybp3Wu8:APA91bHxOact-9gcqf7rAqNSPSkvU7N5h4t4m0XgCAHBdu"
}
```

I do this in onCreate method..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, PostFeedActivity.class);
    if (getIntent().getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("myAction")) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String universityId = extras.getString(getString(R.string.notification_university));

        String notificationId = extras.getString(getString(R.string.notification_id));
        String notificationCreatorName = extras.getString(getString(R.string.notification_creator_name));
        String notificationCreatorImage = extras.getString(getString(R.string.notification_creator_image));
        int notificationCount = extras.getInt(getString(R.string.notification_count), 0);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(notificationId)) {
            intent.setAction(getString(R.string.action_notification_from_push));

            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.notification_count),
                    notificationCount);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.notification_id),
                    notificationId);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.notification_creator_name),
                    notificationCreatorName);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.notification_creator_image),
                    notificationCreatorImage);

            //fetch notification data by calling API and start activity
            requestNotification(notificationId, intent);
            //

        } else {
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kind of late, but for anyone who still encountring the same problem.
U see pending Intent have some FLAGS that will help u to handle intents going through your notifications. And the reason that u've only one responsive notification is that they're calling for the same intent, and in that case the results depend on your pending result FLAG, [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent) refer to this for more informations.
So if u've notifications with same actions or intents it's recomended to set ur pending Intent FLAG to "FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT" so even if there's already an intent  with same action in background/foreground it will open it and update it with the new data from your notification extra, i hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If all your notifications have the same `tag` they are grouped by android and then you only have the latest notification available.
I can not see from your code, whether your `tag` is a unique value (so you show them side-by-side in the notification bar of the device).

As soon as you have a `notification` object and not only `data`, android takes partially control of the notification, means:

- If your app is not running or in background, the notification is shown on notification bar
- If your app is in foreground active, **no notification** is shown, instead, the callback `onMessageReceived` callback is invoked directly in your `FirebaseMessagingService` (this is the callback that is also invoked if you receive a data-only message from FCM)

See also here [FCM notification merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611550/firebase-merge-similar-notifications-in-android/41693045#41693045)

Hope this helps,
cheers

Comment: When the app is on foreground, the notification is working properly. But the my problem appears when the app lis in background. And the **tag** is  unique.

Comment: can you show the code in ``myAction``? How do you process the click?

Comment: I added that to my question :)